# I can not get JPA CriteriaBuilder equal() predicate to be case sensitive

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am building a REST-Interface for some Application and I use JPA and Hibernate to access a SQL-Database.

Now I am trying to check if a given nickname already exists.

I am doing it this way:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<DBUser> query = builder.createQuery(DBUser.class);
Root<DBUser> from = query.from(DBUser.class);
Predicate uniqueNickname = builder.equal(from.get(DBUser_.nickName),newNickname);
query.select(from).where(uniqueNickname);
if (this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().size() == 0) {
   //ok 
} else {
   //not ok
}
```

If I now have a User TEst in the database and newNickname="teST" 
it puts the User TEst into the resultlist.
(I checked what the name in the resultlist is and it says TEst)
I am using the mysql connector "mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, `CriteriaBuilder#equal` is case-sensitive, you can achieve equals ignore case by comparing strings in uppercase variant:

```
Predicate uniqueNickname = builder.equal(builder.upper(from.<String>get(DBUser_.nickName)),
                                         newNickname.toUpperCase());
```

In your case, the DB ignore the case sensitive completely.

Checking your MySQL DB and change the collation setting (the collation with `_ci` suffix is case-insensitve)

Comment: i want equals do not ignore case it currently does equals ignore case

Comment: You have wrong usage somewhere, by default `CriteriaBuilder#equal` is case sensitive

Comment: Forgot to mention the collation setting, change your mysql server setting to make it case-sensitive

Comment: That is what I thought. But what are reasons it could behave the way it currently does? I printed the variable newNickname before and I printed the resultlist-item nickname afterwards and they are different. Also the name is stored case sensitive in the DB

Comment: Change the collation setting in your MySQL server